# How do I append to a Document Term Matrix in R?

Tags: r, tm

I would like to append two Document Term Matrices together. I have one row of data and would like to use different control functions on them (an n-gram tokenizer, removal of stopwords, and wordLength bounds for text, none of these for my non-text fields).

When I use the tm_combine: c(dtm_text,dtm_inputs) it adds the second set as a new row. I want to append these attributes to the same row.

```
library("tm")   

  BigramTokenizer <-
  function(x)
    unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = " "), 
           use.names = FALSE)

# Data to be tokenized
 txt_fields   <- paste("i like your store","i love your products","i am happy")
# Data not to be tokenized
 other_inputs <- paste("cd1_ABC","cd2_555","cd3_7654")

 # NGram tokenize text data 
  dtm_text <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(txt_fields)),
                               control = list(
                                              tokenize = BigramTokenizer,


                                      stopwords=TRUE,
                                                  wordLengths=c(2, Inf),
                                                  bounds=list(global = c(1,Inf))))

    # Do not perform tokenization of other inputs
      dtm_inputs <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(other_inputs)),
                                   control = list(
                                                  bounds = list(global = c(1,Inf))))
    # DESIRED OUTPUT
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 12)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 12/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs am happy happy like like your love love your products products am store store love
   1        1     1    1         1    1         1        1           1     1          1
    Terms
Docs your products your store cd1_abc cd2_555 cd3_7654
   1       1       1        1
   1             1          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [text2vec](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec) (but I'm biased, since I'm the author).

```
library(text2vec)
# Data to be tokenized
txt_fields   <- paste("i like your store","i love your products","i am happy")
# Data not to be tokenized
other_inputs <- paste("cd1_ABC","cd2_555","cd3_7654")
stopwords = tm::stopwords("en")

# tokenize by whitespace
txt_toknens = strsplit(txt_fields, ' ', TRUE)
vocab = create_vocabulary(itoken(txt_toknens), ngram = c(1, 2), stopwords = stopwords)
# if you need word lengths:
# vocab$vocab = vocab$vocab[nchar(terms) > 1]
# but note, it will not remove "i_am", etc.
# you can add word "i" to stopwords to remove such terms
txt_vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)
dtm_text = create_dtm(itoken(txt_fields),  vectorizer = txt_vectorizer)

# also tokenize by whitespace, but won't create bigrams in next step
other_inputs_toknes = strsplit(other_inputs, ' ', TRUE)
vocab_other = create_vocabulary(itoken(other_inputs))
other_vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab_other)
dtm_other = create_dtm(itoken(other_inputs),  vectorizer = other_vectorizer)
# combine
result = cbind(dtm_text, dtm_other)
```

Comment: @Ddmitriy Selivanov - looks like a really good solution, but was hoping to result in a DocumentTextMatrix formatted object. This returns a sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix". 

There are two features of DocumentTermMatrix I need to use (are these possible in the dgCMatrix format?)
1. findFreqterms(result,<low_freq>). This will let me restrict to the terms with > n occurances.
2. dictionary = . This will let me create a validation set with the same terms from my training set.

Is this possible?

Comment: that works! for completeness, here is how I can do the equivalent of findFreqTerms on a matrix

colnames(result[,colSums(result) > 1])

Comment: check text2vec vignettes. Managment of dictionaries/vocabularies is very simple and straightforward. For findFreqTerms you even don't need DTM, text2vec vocabulary already contains this information. See `create_vocabulary()` and `prune_vocabulary()` functions.

Comment: For the validation set, just create dtm from new documents using vocabularies from train set and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

```
dtm_combined = as.DocumentTermMatrix(cbind(dtm_text, dtm_inputs), weighting = weightTf)
inspect(dtm_combined)
# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 8)>>
#     Non-/sparse entries: 8/0
# Sparsity           : 0%
# Maximal term length: 8
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
# 
# Terms
# Docs happy like love products store cd1_abc cd2_555 cd3_7654
# 1     1    1    1        1     1       1       1        1
```

But it will give wrong results if you have the same words in the `dtm_text` and in the `dtm_inputs`. This words won't be combined and will appear twice in the `dtm_combined`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. This isn't quite what I am looking for.

My specific issue is that I want to apply bigram tokenization to the text and not the inputs. Bigram tokenization combines terms into word pairs: ("I like your store") becomes ("I like", "like your", "your store"). I don't want to apply bigram tokenization for the code inputs. It doesn't make sense to view ("cd1_abc cd2_555", "cd2555 cd3_7653").

Comment: @ChrisL There are no bigramms in your example of the desired output. What I misunderand?

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer to show the desired output 

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 12)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 12/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs am happy happy like like your love love your products products am store store love
   1        1     1    1         1    1         1        1           1     1          1
    Terms
Docs your products your store cd1_abc cd2_555 cd3_7654
   1       1       1        1
   1             1          1

Comment: @ChrisL As far as I can see you want in your output single words as well as bigrams? Or not?

Comment: that's correct. I'd like to see single words and bigrams for the text. Only single words for the other inputs. I'm having trouble applying the bigram tokenizer to only the text. And if I create two document text matrices (one for text, one for other inputs), I am unable to combine them.